In Datahub, when ingesting from multiple source with same siblings, all siblings not coming under 1 entity
When we ingest data from multiple sources (example dbt + hive, trino + hive). where sibling dataset is same (hive in our case). All the components (hive, dbt, trino) should be visible under 1 entity.
For dbt, it's composed of dbt and hive

similarly, for trino; it's composed of trino and hive.
However, it should come as composed of trino, dbt, and hive
